# DAX compare to previous row and update upstream rows per condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggling in solving the following requirement on table attached.
I need to create a “Cross location” column where the result of the column looks on previous row and compares if the value on the location column matches.
If it does than the output is “No” but if it doesn’t it outputs “Yes” to all upstream rows of the Group which is indexed by the task number column.

** This is as small portion of the table which consists many groups and multiple task numbers which not always starts with 1 put per group is always consecutive.

Appreciate your support - table of interest attached in picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Gh9.png)

```
Group   task number location    Cross location
A   1   CAT  
A   2   CAT No
A   3   TGR Yes
A   4   TGR Yes
A   5   JGR Yes
A   6   CAT Yes
B   19  JGR  
B   20  CAT Yes
B   21  CAT Yes
B   22  TGR Yes
```

Comment: Why task number 4 TGR is YES?

Comment: This is a requirement for future visualization of the data. I need that once a cross location is defined as such all upstream will be as so. regardless if on this example task #3 to task#4 is not a cross lab per definition.

Comment: Please explain in simple words, just say the logic for calculating Yes and No.

Comment: For each group once it gets the first time cross lab ( = location of task number i <> location of task number i-1) all i+1 rows will be also defined as cross lab as row i.

Comment: Can you provide expected values in the Cross location column and explain what logic lies behind it? In general, if you want to calculate something based on previous rows, you would need to provide an index column, which would indicate current vs previous rows. Then, you would `FILTER` your table by the index column (values lower than current row - future hint - see `EARLIER` function).

Comment: Group   task number    location    Cross location
A                 1                 CAT  
A                 2                 CAT              No
A                 3                 TGR             Yes
A                 4                 TGR             Yes
A                 5                 JGR             Yes
A                 6                 CAT             Yes
B                 19               JGR  
B                  20              CAT             Yes
B                  21              CAT             Yes
B                  22              TGR             Yes